# Format code stored in mysql database table column using php

Tags: php, mysql, pretty-print

I was trying to build a blog system and I have stored the contents being 4000 characters in length. The blog post contains  statements along with html text. The contents within these  may contain code in any implementation language. The text is loosing formatting when i copy the text to the sql database , and I would like to retain the indentation within the data , or need some javascript library that will prettify the output of the pre statements on ouput from a mysql query statement.

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: use nl2br() function

Comment: You say it's "*losing the formatting when [you] copy the text to the sql database*", but **how have you determined** that it's during that step that the problem occurs?  Please include your diagnostic methods and outcomes.  Based on what you've said so far, it might actually be that the problem is occurring during data retrieval or (more likely) display/rendering.  For example, have you applied the [`white-space: pre`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space) CSS style (to preserve whitespace during rendering within the browser)?

Comment: @eggyal actually when i copy-paste the formatted code into the mysql server using phpMyAdmin Interface , all the necessary indentation is lost . Is there any way to preserve that . Some say that if you insert data into a mysql  using a textarea form , the necessary indentations remain part of the data. I need an affirmation to this approach...since this could be one of the negative aspects of using gui tools like phpMyadmin.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  **How have you determined that the indentation was lost during insertion and not during retrieval/rendering?**  It's most likely to be that the data is in MySQL with indentation preserved, but that it is not being displayed to you when you view it.

Comment: @eggyal By  manually checking the data in the database, mysql seems to trim whitespaces when copying text to it directly using phpmyadmin , hence i am writing a dynamic blog form and will be encoding the input to preserve the indentation using encodeURI function. Will post as soon as i am done.

Comment: I really do hate to appear pedantic, but you're still not answering the question.  What does "*by manually checking the data in the database*" mean?  How have you done that?  Using what command in what tools, and what was the response?

Comment: @eggyal I already mentioned I am using phpMyadmin interface to insert data into the database and I am able to see all the indentation is lost. PhpMyadmin also provides for browser transformation option , to map db information with browser based element and I have selected "plain/text with formatting " option but I don't get the desired effects.

Comment: Issue Resolved:

1. I needed to submit the blog information in an encoded format , inorder to preserve the indenation information  (I used urlencode() function of php).

2. In the receiving end , I used urldecode() and put the contents inside a <pre></pre> and the result was the expected result.Finally !!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some javascript code formater and beautifier:

This little beautifier will reformat and reindent bookmarklets, ugly JavaScript, unpack scripts
To beautify using python:

```
$ pip install jsbeautifier
$ js-beautify file.js
```

Beautified output goes to stdout.
Find more info here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

A Javascript module and CSS file that allows syntax highlighting of source code snippets in an html page.

https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

It need some effort to research on google what we require. What you can do too before posting any question.
Hope here is the inforamtion what you required
https://github.com/stevenbenner/identify-indent

Comment: No relevent to what i was asking for...i needed to preetify code not to style. Also I don't need any python stuff here.